# ajaxfosuserbundle registration symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using AjaxFOSuserBundle

and trying to make registration via ajax, but getting an error. What does it mean?

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationListener::authenticate() must be an instance of FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent, instance of Tecnocreaciones\Bundle\AjaxFOSUserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent given

```
$(function ()
{
    $('form#fos_user_registration_form').submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(e.currentTarget);

        inputs = {};
        // Send all form's inputs
        $.each($this.find('input'), function (i, item) {
            var $item = $(item);
            inputs[$item.attr('name')] = $item.val();
        });
        // Send form into ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: $this.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: inputs,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.has_error) {
                    // Insert your error process
                    alert('WRONG');
                }
                else {
                    // Insert your success process
                    alert('check your email!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: yeap... you can see it already

Comment: Can you give us the code in the registerAction method in your registrationController?

Comment: Look please at link below... I'm using this bundle

Answer (score 0):

- It seems to be a problem with the AjaxFOSUserBundle code.
  The FilterUserResponseEvent from AjaxFOSUserBundle should extends FOSUserBundle class.

You should post your issue on the github project.

- The other solution could be to overwrite the registration controller of FosUserBundle (ajaxfosuserbundle extends the fosuserbundle) to fix the event:
  http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html
  Or by redefining the register route.
  https://github.com/Tecnocreaciones/AjaxFOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L123

Comment: Yeap.. i think so too. So what solution you see here?